# Logistic Regression Model with Non-Independent Regressors

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, predictive-models, independence

I'm looking to create a model that takes into account multiple logistic variables in an ordered process. To illustrate, what I'm trying to do is

similar to the following:

```
Profit = (Option1)(Profit_Option1) + (Option2)(Profit_Option2) + (Option3)(Profit_Option3) + ...
```

In a sense, I would be looking for:

```
E(Profit) = P(Option1)(E(Profit_Option1)) + P(Option2|!Option1)(E(Profit_Option2)) + P(Option3|!(Option1 or Option2))(E(Profit_Option3)) + ...
```

All of the events are mutually exclusive--that is to say, if '1' codes for the usage of an option, and '0' codes for the non-usage of an option,

then there can be at most one option coded as a '1' for any given observation. There is also the possibility for every option to be coded as '0'

signifying that none of the options were use (and thus zero profit).

The issue that I suspect I will run into is due to the fact that these options are ordered, there are likely to be collinearity effects. So Option2's value will "depend" on Option1's, and Option3's value will "depend" on both Option1 and Option2. This is not acceptable since ultimately, the type of question I'm looking to answer is if we take out Option2 for example, what would the effect on expected profit be?

How should I address this potential issue? Is there an elegant way out there? I can't imagine this being an uncommon problem and have combed Google and Cross Validated extensively but maybe I'm not searching the right terms... Hoping someone else has had a similar problem and has a reasonable solution.

Please don't hesitate if anything needs clarification.

Comment: I can spot two issues with your question. The first being that the outcome of logistic regression is in the range <0,1>, not necessarily the predictors. If Profit is predicted, then you would need (non-)linear regression. Second, if you would take out option 2, how would you know how P(Option1) or P(Option3) are affected? Would those with Option2 maybe switch to the competition?

Comment: Ahhh you are correct about the range of logistic regression being in the range <0,1>, so I will correct that in the original post.

If I took out Option2, then P(Option3) and beyond would be affected (but not P(Option1)). You can think of it as Option2's customers would end being divvied up by the remaining Options (3, 4, etc.). Option1 is more profitable than Option2, which is in turn more profitable than Option3. What I meant by Option3's value "depending" on Option2 and Option1 is that Option3 only comes into play if the preceding options fail.

Comment: O.k., I don't think we got ahead much in the end; reviewing your question for the second it does not look like a regression at all. You are looking at some expected value. Is this not solvable by just doing basic math?